# Передать любой тип как аргумент (с указанием типа) в C++

Tags: c++

Видел в некоторых исходниках конструкцию типа `Function<DWORD>(123)`. Подскажите пожалуйста:

1. Как называется конструкция `<DWORD>`?
2. Как её использовать?

Нагуглил, что нужен `template <typename T>`, но как его использовать в заголовочном файле? Указал так же, как и в исходнике, при запуске пишет

> "Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl TestFunc(unsigned long)" (??$TestFunc@K@@YAHK@Z) в функции _main Project1"

Comment: Ну вот как в одном ответе уложить то, на что нужны, по-хорошему, книги? См. в учебниках/книгах типа "для чайников" - шаблоны C++, обобщенное программирование...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простейший пример:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
void function(T x) {
  std::cout << x;
}

int main() {
  int a = 42;
  double b = 42.0;  

  function(a);
  function(b);
}
```

1) `template id`

2) не понятен вопрос; так и используйте, как сами написали

3) скорее всего, вы сделали объявление в h файле, а реализацию в cpp, поэтому линкер не может найти реализацию

Comment: Сделал объявление и там и там, ошибка осталась.

Comment: @Алексей Петродий: Какая ошибка?

Comment: "Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl TestFunc(unsigned long)" (??$TestFunc@K@@YAHK@Z) в функции _main Project1"

Comment: @Алексей Петродий: Так не бывает. Но что вы там на самом деле наобъявляли - нам отсюда не видно.

Comment: @trust, Вы наверное не очень понятно выразились и автор не понял Вашу мысль. А мысль в том, что реализация шаблонных функций должна находиться в h файле, нельзя её переносить в cpp файл.